# Can normal users access iphone apps source files?

Tags: ios, app-store

There are some source files for iphone apps with the formats such as .m & .h

I want to know whether normal users or developers can access such files when you put an app into AppStore.

Comment: no, anyone can't use core file

Comment: Have you tried it yourself? I know I'd be using the AppStore more if I could access source :)

Comment: I no tried . but I want to know about it!!!

Comment: With a jailbroken device, someone can see your method signatures and property names but couldn't see the whole source code.

Comment: @BoranA what do you mean by whole source code???

Comment: I want to know anyone can see my .m files???

Comment: No, but they can take a plain string inside of them. If you describe a variable named password they can track it or they can inject code in to your method. Better read some articles about it.

Comment: Not any variable, only properties (which are actually setter/getter *methods*). Variables become anonymous memory addresses once the program is compiled; there is no 'name' (character string) attached to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not access these files.you can see only resources of the app.